# Grails: how to access mongodb via SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl, grails

I wrote a grails 3.3 + mongo 4.0.4 app but in production the mongo server only accepts connections via SSL (self signed cert). I haven't found anywhere documentation on how to configure GORM for mongo (http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/). There is an option (sslEnabled and I assume I should use the socketFactory) for using SSL enabled connections in grails but I'm not sure how to configure the connection

Comment: Using what with Grails exactly? GORM? Or just the plain Java Driver?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I wasn't clear. I'm editing my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it has the exact same issue with me, I still don't have a proper way of connecting to a mongodb from grails directly using SSL. The indirect solution that I've found is to deploy on the machine that runs grails a mongos client (mongo sharding client) enable SSL in order to connect to the database but leave the local connection without encryption. Thus, I can access the remote database securely via SSL but still connect using clear connection between mongos and grails. The mongos config should look like this:

```
net:
  ssl:
    mode: preferSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /installDir/cert.pem
    CAFile: /installDir/chain.pem
    clusterFile: /installDir/cert.pem

  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  clusterAuthMode: x509
```

The preferSSL allows mongos to connect using SSL to the database and still allow the grails app to connect cleartext to mongos

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to connect without mongos.

You need to specify `socketFactory` instance in `grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy` to validate server certificate

```
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString
import grails.mongodb.MongoSSLContextBuilder

grails.mongodb = [
        url    : new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://username:password@hostname/dbname?authSource=admin&tls=true"),
        options: [
                autoConnectRetry: true,
                connectTimeout  : 300,
                sslEnabled      : true,
                socketFactory   : new MongoSSLContextBuilder().getSSLContext("private/mongo/ca-certificate.crt").getSocketFactory()
        ]
]
```

Impementation of `MongoSSLContextBuilder`

```
package grails.mongodb

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.grails.io.support.ClassPathResource

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory
import java.security.KeyStore
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

@CompileStatic
@Slf4j
class MongoSSLContextBuilder {
    SSLContext getSSLContext(String pathToCert) {
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(getCert(pathToCert));

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ks.load(null);
            ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);

            tmf.init(ks);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

            return sslContext;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error during building mongo ssl context: ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private InputStream getCert(String pathToCert) throws IOException {
        return new ClassPathResource(pathToCert).getInputStream();
    }

}
```

Put your `ca-certificate.crt` under `src/main/resources` directory

If you need `mongodb+srv://` protocol to work you need to update `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver` library in `build.gradle` to version at least 3.6.0

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.4'

    compile('org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.6') {
        exclude group: 'org.mongodb', module: 'mongodb-driver'
    }
```